# How to fix a DIV-Container next right to a centered Container - CSS

Tags: html, css

I've a simple DIV-Container for the main-content of the webpage. I.E

```
#main { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Now I would like to fix another container, right and fixed at the top of the #main-Container. See Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do something like the following using CSS Flex:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(66.66% - 20px);
  float: right;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 33.33%;
}

.main:first-child {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  max-width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="main red">
    Main content
  </div>

  <div class="main green">
    ?
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm missing the centered red box in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the green div inside the centered div and style it.

```
<div id="main" style="position:relative;">
   <div id="green_div" style="position:absolute; left:100%; margin-left:20px; background:green;">
   <div>
</div>
```